# How to check if time is past a certain amount of time with strtotime?

Tags: php, unix

I'd like to know how I can check if the time is after a specific amount of minutes with an else if more than two hours.. I tried the following but it does not seem to work..

`$postTime` is in unix time.

```
if(strtotime("+20 minutes") > strtotime($postTime))
{
    echo 'REFRESH EVERY 20 minutes';

} else if(strtotime("+2 hours")> strtotime($postTime))
{
    echo 'refresh every 2 hours';
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of checking if it's past a specific amount of minutes/hours or with strtotime is the best way?

EDIT:

```
If $postTime = 11:30

If(time is now 11:50 compared to $postTime){
 good
} else if(time is now 1:30 compared to $postTime){
good
} else {
do nothing;
}
```

else if time has passed over 2 hours compared to postTime

Comment: We can do it using JavaScript function setInterval

Comment: @kannan because he's not using javascript.

Comment: This is a fine way to check a time interval, its as efficient as you need

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement would always match unless `$postTime` is time more than 20 minutes in the future, you aren't checking if `$postTime` was 20 minutes ago.

`strtotime()` wouldn't be the most efficient way of doing this, the most efficient way of doing this would just be using arithmetic on integers.  Time functions of php (including time and strtotime) return a unix timestamp integer.

The easiest way of doing so:

```
// If $postTime is a unix timestamp integer
if ( $postTime < (time()-(60*20)) ) {
...
}

// The above statement is equivalent to:
if ( $postTime < strtotime("-20 minutes") ) {
...
}

// If $postTime is a string
if ( strtotime($postTime) < (time()-(60*20)) ) {

}
```

Comment: I edited up the question, because I still can't see to understand why it wouldn't work the way it is then.

Comment: @iBrazilian2, I have edited my answer in accordance with your edit.  You're checking against a future time, not checking if $postTime was x minutes in the past.